# SeekableByteChannel.read() always returns 0, InputStream is fine

Tags: java, nio

We have a data file for which we need to generate a CRC.  (As a placeholder, I'm using CRC32 while the others figure out what CRC polynomial they actually want.)  This code seems like it ought to work:

**broken:**

```
Path in = ......;

try (SeekableByteChannel reading =
    Files.newByteChannel (in, StandardOpenOption.READ))
{
System.err.println("byte channel is a " + reading.getClass().getName() +
  " from " + in + " of size " + reading.size() + " and isopen=" + reading.isOpen());
    java.util.zip.CRC32 placeholder = new java.util.zip.CRC32();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate (reasonable_buffer_size);

    int bytesread = 0;
    int loops = 0;
    while ((bytesread = reading.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        byte[] raw = buffer.array();
System.err.println("Claims to have read " + bytesread + " bytes, have buffer of size " + raw.length + ", updating CRC");
        placeholder.update(raw);
        loops++;
        buffer.clear();
    }
    // do stuff with placeholder.getValue()
}
catch (all the things that go wrong with opening files) {
    and handle them;
}
```

The `System.err` and `loops` stuff is just for debugging; we don't actually care how many times it takes.  The output is:

`byte channel is a sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl from C:\working\tmp\ls2kst83543216xuxxy8136.tmp of size 7196 and isopen=true
finished after 0 time(s) through the loop`

There's no way to run the real code inside a debugger to step through it, but from looking at the source to `sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read()` it looks like a 0 is returned if the file magically becomes closed while internal data structures are prepared; the code below is copied from the Java 7 reference implementation, comments added by me:

```
// sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.java
public int read(ByteBuffer dst) throws IOException {
    ensureOpen();              // this throws if file is closed...
    if (!readable)
        throw new NonReadableChannelException();
    synchronized (positionLock) {
        int n = 0;
        int ti = -1;
        Object traceContext = IoTrace.fileReadBegin(path);
        try {
            begin();
            ti = threads.add();
            if (!isOpen())
                return 0;       // ...argh
            do {
                n = IOUtil.read(fd, dst, -1, nd);
            } while (......)
.......
```

But the debugging code tests `isOpen()` and gets true.  So I don't know what's going wrong.

As the current test data files are tiny, I dropped this in place just to have something working:

**works for now:**

```
try {
    byte[] scratch = Files.readAllBytes(in);
    java.util.zip.CRC32 placeholder = new java.util.zip.CRC32();
    placeholder.update(scratch);
    // do stuff with placeholder.getValue()
}
```

I don't want to slurp the entire file into memory for the Real Code, because some of those files can be *large*.  I do note that `readAllBytes` uses an InputStream in its reference implementation, which has no trouble reading the same file that SeekableByteChannel failed to.  So I'll probably rewrite the code to just use input streams instead of byte channels.  I'd still like to figure out what's gone wrong in case a future scenario comes up where we *need* to use byte channels.  What am I missing with `SeekableByteChannel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that 'reasonable_buffer_size' isn't zero.

Comment: It's currently hardcoded to 32K.  I don't believe they have any plans to make the buffer size adjustable at runtime; it's just one of those constants that gets a name instead of a literal integer.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't zero when you call read()? The only way it can return zero is if you provide a zero length buffer or one that is already full, or in non-blocking mode which doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: `final int reasonable_buffer_size = 32 * 1024;` seems pretty nonzero.  :-)  But I see what you mean; I'll try decreasing to a really tiny buffer when I'm back in the lab and see what happens.  The buffer should be empty when `allocate()` returns, and I remember that adding a preemptive call to `clear()` anyhow had no effect.

Comment: Le sigh.  Ant code generation conspired to bite us in our shiny metal butts, as Bender would say.  What was being typed in the source file doesn't necessarily resemble what gets spit out in the class file...